# Symfony lock file not up to date even after running composer update

Tags: git, updates, composer-php, cloudcontrol

I just ran a `composer update` on my local machine for my Symfony2 app, which also updated the projects `composer.lock` file.

Now I `git add -A` and `git commit` changes.

But when I `git push` my repository to my cloudControl deployment, I get the message:

```
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update
to update them.
```

I just ran the update. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that if you get this on a remote machine after running update locally the only explanation is that you did not commit the composer.lock file.

Comment: I sure did. It was the only modification. I would've gotten a "Everything up-to-date" message if I didn't commit. By the way: Wouldn't this rather be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Yes well I always find the line between comment and answer to be quite blurry. In any case this is very weird, but it means the md5 of composer.json doesn't match the stored `hash` in composer.lock for some obscure reason. Could be you are on windows and have CRLF line endings in composer.json but on the cloudControl deploy it's checked out with LF line endings only? Apart from that I can't imagine what would cause this.

Comment: So actually you get the "Everything up-to-date" message if you did not commit or push the same commit twice. Remember with Git you commit locally and then push to the remote. If the remote says, "Everything up-to-date" your pushing the exact same state. In your question you're only talking about updating since this is not a Git command I'm not sure what this is supposed to mean.

Comment: Well, I ran the update, which changes the `composer.lock` file in my repository. And when I push, I **did not** get an Everything-up-to-date message (see above, I **would have gotten** that message, if nothing was changed or commited). So I pushed the just updated lock file but get the message, that I need to run update? Strange!